# Create JSON data in specific format

Tags: javascript, php, json, pdo

I need to create data as this:

```
{v: 1.0, f: '<h1>1.0</h1>'}
```

...

but now I only know how to get first parametr so I get:`{v: 1.0}`,

with this code:

```
 $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $naziv);
```

what I need to add to my code: `$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $naziv);` to get like this json: `{v: 1.0, f: '<h1>1.0</h1>'}`

Comment: Your desired data does not conform to JSON standards. Property names are in quotes.

Comment: Your target should be `{"v": "1.0", "f": "<h1>1.0</h1>"}`

Comment: Don't build your own JSON in PHP. Use `json_encode`. It will build it correctly if you give it an object: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$naziv = 1.0;
$header ='<h1>1.0</h1>';

$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $naziv,
                'f' => (string) $header
          );

echo json_encode($temp);
```

or

```
$naziv = 1.0;
$header ='<h1>1.0</h1>';

$temp['v'] = $naziv;
$temp['f'] = $header;

echo json_encode($temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$naziv = 1.0;

$temp = array(
    "v" => $naziv
    "f" => "<h1>{$naziv}</h1>",
);

echo json_encode($temp);
```

This will result in

```
{"v":1.0,"f":"<h1>1.0</h1>"}
```

Comment: this give me an error when I try to write this:     $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $naziv, 'f': '<h1>'.$naziv.'</h1>');